# How can I get access to the folder that I've copied to /opt?

Tags: permissions

I've just copied a folder named `journey` to the `/opt` directory of home folder using the following command:

```
sudo cp -r '/media/B60EB9810EB93B67/xampp/htdocs/journey/' '/opt/lampp/htdocs'
```

Now I can't open the folder `journey`. It says:

> You are not the owner.

How can I get full access to this folder?

Comment: With a little compilation of `sudo chown` but please be careful with chown. This command is supposed to change the ownership of files. Take a look at `man chown` or search the web how to use it.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `sudo chmod -R ug+rw /opt/lampp/htdocs`

Answer (score 1):

If this is to access `/opt/lampp/htdocs` I would start with

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Then you should be able to do a `cd /opt/lampp/htdocs` and acces the files there.

- Try to refrain from changing `/opt` since some software depend on being owned by root.
- This is a fairly common 'problem' and understanding permissions is fundamental to understanding Linux and even more so fundamental to understanding how to protect your software. I would read up on permissions for Linux based file systems if I was you.
- I know it is just a directory name you used but lamp != xamp ;)

Answer (score 0):

As @Rinzwind mentioned some softwares need the folder to be owned by root. Although I have been having a similar problem and changing the folder's right to myself didn't affected the way lampp behaved and I was able to use it just the way it was supposed to work.
I just used nautilus to change the permissions through the properties of htdocs folder. You can do the same for your journey or htdocs folder.
You just have to open terminal and type

```
sudo nautilus
```

and then provide your password. After that move to the

```
/opt/lampp
```

folder and then right click on `htdocs` and chose `properties`. Then find `permissions` and change it to yourself. Assign the owner to yourself as well as the group to be yourself. Chose `read and write`. And you are good enough to go and do any modification that you want with your folder.